# Torelli theorem for cubic hypersurfaces

Tags: hodge-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the paper of Claire Voisin on the Torelli theorem for cubic hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^5$ (in french : http://www.springerlink.com/content/j8675gn214l17523/). Are there lecture notes, or survey articles, or a book on that subject, with full details ? There are a lot of 'clairement' and 'évident'...

In the last section of the paper for example, she proves that the period map, extended to the locus $\Delta$ of cubics with one node (after a degre 2 ramified cover) has maximal rank along $\Delta$. The Clemens-Schmid sequences seems a little different from the one in Peters-Steenbrink and I am not sure about the precise meaning of 'the period map essentially gives this Hodge structure, from what it is obvious that we can reconstruct this other one, etc...'

Comment: In the case you have not yet seen it, there exists an alternative proof by Looijenga. The period map for cubic fourfolds http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0951

Comment: The link to Voisin's paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. Perhaps it is meant to point to the following one—? _Voisin, Claire_, [**Théorème de Torelli pour les cubiques de $\mathbb{P}^5$**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01389270), Invent. Math. 86, 577–601 (1986). [Zbl 0622.14009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0622.14009). [**Erratum**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-008-0116-z), Invent. Math. 172, No. 2, 455–458 (2008). [Zbl 1133.14310](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1133.14310).